# Change block/cluster size in unattend.xml

Tags: unattended, wds

Is there a way to change the block/cluster size when formatting a disk using unattend.xml & Windows Deployment Services?  It keeps defaulting to 1024k, and I need something smaller.

Comment: Why do you need something smaller?

Comment: it was an old image that WDS was having trouble restoring, and we suspected it was partially because the cluster size was different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be not possible (at least with current implementation).  You can bring up the console and do it manually if its really necessary though.